# Joomla override - displaying different contact categories on same page underneath each other

Tags: joomla, overriding, contacts

Hi dear stackeroverflowers,

i have different contact categories:
cat1 cat2 and cat3

one menulink:
categories

i want to display the contacts beside each other so when you click the menulink "categories" you get the follow view:

**cat1**

contactcat1 contactcat1 contactcat1 contactcat1

**cat2**

contactcat2 contactcat2 contactcat2 contactcat2

**cat3**

contactcat 3 contactcat3

---

the standard view have to be modified in /html/com_contact/category/default_items.php i guess

can anyone help? googled a lot and this problem is common but there is no answer i can get.

Comment: Try to add the code you are trying to modify in your question.

Comment: No you need to override the categorIES view not the category view.